# TkInter Making a large number of cells with Grid, while using Geometry property

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I want to make a lot of rows and columns on Tkinter Grid geometry manager.
As you may know, while using the Geometry property to set a specific height and weight to a window, you have to specify rowconfigure and columnconfigure ( Correct me if im wrong. )

I wanted to do this:

`for x in range(10):`

`root.rowconfigure(x, weight=1)`

As it is obvious, it just creates a row with weight 1 on the last range number.
This should be easy to do, but I dont see how right now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, if you *don't* specify a window geometry, the window will automatically size itself to fit its contents. And FWIW, you aren't required to call `rowconfigure` or `columnconfigure` - all `grid` rows and columns will have the same weight by default unless specified.

Comment: @JRiggles: it's a best practice to give at least one row and one column a non-zero weight if you care about your UI being responsive to the user resizing the window.

Comment: @JRiggles I am aware, however I want that specific geometry for the window this time. Thanks

Comment: @BryanOakley Good to know! Out of curiosity, what happens if I don't?

Comment: @JRiggles: if you don't, and the window is resized to be bigger than the widgets inside, you'll end up with unused parts of the window (ie: the widgets won't stretch all the way to the edges).

Comment: @BryanOakley no kidding - it doesn’t refresh the grid? Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @JRiggles it’t not a matter of refreshing, it’s that rows and columns by default don’t grow any bigger than they need to be unless you instruct them to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row and Column configure has nothing to do with your 'geometry', but with the size of the widget you are trying to assemble your grid, if it is the root, then yes it will have a direct connection with the geometry, you are forgetting the 'index ' when calling configuration, here's an example of how it would work with root.

```py
from random import choice
from tkinter import *


colors = ['blue','red','green', 'purple','dark red']
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

rows = 10
columns = 10

for i in range(rows):
    root.rowconfigure(index=i,weight=1)

for i in range(columns):
    root.columnconfigure(index=i, weight=1)

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(columns):
        lbl  = Label(root,bg=choice(colors))
        lbl.grid(row=r,column=c,sticky='news')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you so much. I didnt know I needed the index=, it works without it if I do it outside the for.